# UPDATE statement in SQL half working half not doing anything

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I can't for the life of me figure out what the heck I'm doing wrong.  The words, A LOT, comes to mind.  But right now I have got half of the `UPDATE` to work but can't get the rest of it to work.

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

If Me.butCompleteFlight.Value = True Then
    SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strLand = values('" & Me.strStopTime & "') WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
    SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strWorkingRecord = FALSE WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

the strWorkingRecord switching from `TRUE` to `FALSE` works.  The issue I'm having is the strLand is not populating, I used the same syntax as the `INSERT` sql that I used in a different section of the database but can't find out what I'm messing up on this one.

Thanks

Comment: SQL is a string and you assign 2 values to it one after the other. When you execute DoCmd.RunSQL SQL it contains the last value that you have assigned to it.

Comment: Who can answer this: where is the **typo** or the **problem that can't be reproduced** in this question?

Answer (score 2):

`SQL` is a string and you assign 2 values to it one after the other. When you execute `DoCmd.RunSQL SQL` it contains the last value that you have assigned to it.
Execute each statement separately:

```
SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strLand = '" & Me.strStopTime & "' WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strWorkingRecord = FALSE WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Or you can do it in 1 statement like this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE tblFlightRecords SET strLand = '" & Me.strStopTime & "', strWorkingRecord = FALSE WHERE strWorkingRecord = TRUE"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

Also the `VALUES` clause in an `UPDATE` statement is wrong. You can use it only in an `INSERT` statement.